# What is the difference on each sentence? "A policeman stopped a car." vs "A policeman made a car stopped."

Tags: sentence-meaning

Background situation was that a policeman is on road in a car approaching the policeman.

1. A policeman stopped a car.
   In this situation I think that the policeman directly contacted the car to stop it.
2. A policeman made a car stopped.

But in this situation other than first situation, I think the policeman didn't directly contact the car to stop it. Just another element stopped the car directly following the order. For example a driver in the car pulled over or another policeman stopped the car directly.

Is my thinking right?

Comment: To *stop a car* in this context means "to direct the driver of the vehicle to bring the car to a halt".

Answer (score 1):

```
The policeman stopped a car.
```

This means that the policeman with or without physical contact caused the car to stop.

EXAMPLES:

> The policeman talked to the suicidal man on the bridge for 1 hour.
>   Eventually he stopped the man from jumping to his death. (no physical
>   contact)
>
> The policeman grabbed the child stopping him from running into the
>   busy intersection. (physical contact)

---

```
X made/forced Y to <verb>
```

This is used when X forces/commands Y to do a certain action. This usually implies that Y doesn't want to do the action.

Examples:

> Mrs. Jones made Billy clean up the room as punishment for starting the
>   food fight.
>
> The policeman made the driver stop his car.

---

```
The policeman made the car stop.
```

To me this gives me the impression that the policeman somehow coerced the car into stopping itself. It can be used to show what caused an intransitive verb to occur.

EXAMPLES:

> Waving your hand in front of the sensor will make this door open.
>
> The magician made the card disappear and reappear in my shoe.

Comment: "X made/forced Y to <verb>" is understood by me as "X made **to** <verb>" and "X forced Y to <verb>". But it is meant as "X made <verb>" (**without** "to") and "x forced Y to <verb>", isn't it?